# Easily show mean value for plotly express bar plot

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-express

Plotly Express's bar chart stacks the observations by default, showing the sum.

```
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px

df =sns.load_dataset("penguins")

px.bar(data_frame=df, x="species", y="bill_depth_mm")
```

I'm trying to display the mean for each species, which is what most other popular Python libraries return.

I could manually calculate the mean of each species and make a new dictionary/Data Frame. However I feel like there should be an easy way to display the mean directly from Plotly.

I've checked the docs and SO with no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. I imagine what the Plotly developers had in mind is that DataFrames being passed to the `px.bar` method have one y-value per unique category as evidenced by [this documentation](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/#plotly-express-works-with-long-wide-and-mixedform-data) showing how Plotly Express works with long or wide format data. In the medals dataset, there are 9 bars for 9 unique categories.

As you said, this means that you would need to calculate the mean for each unique species, and this can be accomplished by passing a groupby mean of your DataFrame directly to the `data_frame` parameter, even if it's not the most elegant.

```
fig = px.bar(
    data_frame=df.groupby(['species']).mean().reset_index(), 
    x="species", 
    y="bill_depth_mm"
)
```

[image]